# Trying to install Ubuntu for the first time

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I need help with installing Ubuntu on a different partition on my hp Pavilion 15 Laptop. Installation is always stuck at the install updates page and loads for hours after I try to continue from that page.
Things to note:
I have a separate partition (100 GB) I intend to use for this installation.
I have flashed the ISO image unto a USB already.
I have disabled secure boot.
I intend to use both Windows and Ubuntu on the same PC but in different partitions (I mostly need explanation on how to go about this).

My PC was recently infected by malware and someone recommended Linux as a more secure OS.

Comment: If it's *always stuck at the install updates* then don't install updates, there an option for that. Later, after the OS is installed you can troubleshoot that. Of note: Disabling Windows's Fast Startup feature is a must when dual-booting with any Windows 8 or newer (and obviously nothing older should be used anyway because out of support).

Comment: You've not provided any Ubuntu product/release details; nor mentioned if your validated the ISO to ensure download was perfect, or the write of ISO to media (*using the method appropriate for your unstated product/release*) to ensure you don't have install issues. Your other alternative to those checks is scanning logs at install time, but that's not really easier for 1st timers.